# git clone always clone the same repo no matter what url I provide

Tags: git, heroku, clone, bitbucket

No matter what git clone url I use, git always clones one of my old projects from bitbucket. For example when I do something like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/heroku/php-getting-started.git
```

instead of cloning from heroku, I get one of my projects (always the same project) from my bitbucket repository. 
I have tried to remove all the keys associated with the ssh, and create the new ones, but whatever I do the result is the same. Please help. Thank you 
Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: What does this `git clone` command output? Do you, by any chance, already have a non-empty subdirectory called `php-getting-started` in your current directory?

Comment: it just starts cloning the wrong project (the progress percentage runs to completion). And also I don't have an empty directory called    `php-getting-started` here is the output:      'Cloning into 'php-getting-started'...
remote: Counting objects: 1533, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1521/1521), done.
remote: Total 1533 (delta 1174), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (1533/1533), 430.58 KiB | 267.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1174/1174), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
'  .

Comment: Did you alias `git clone` by any chance?  Or just `git` for that matter?

Comment: I am not super sure about that. How can I check that, or if that is the reason how can i revert it?

Comment: Check if you have any `instead-of` in your .gitconfig file

For alias also, you can check the contents of your .gitconfig file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. It didn't matter which repo I tried to clone, it always cloned the same repo each time. Even reinstalling git with purge and autoremove did not help.

Eventually I located my .gitconfig file in my home directory and found the following settings:

```
[user]
    email = <my_email>@gmail.com
    name = Tim Bushell
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@gitlab.com:<name_of_same_repo>.git
```

I edited this file to:

```
[user]
    email = <my_email>@gmail.com
    name = Tim Bushell
```

... and I was able to clone any repo once again.

I'm not clear how the .gitconfig gained this setting.