# How to checkout from git repository in Intellij Idea?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

there's a problem :

I used to have a local repository on my machine, which i deleted eventually. I checkout from it in  Intellij Idea and deleted it from my github as well. Every time i try to clone other repositories from github using url ( File -> New -> Project from Version Control -> Git) i'm getting the message **Clone failed: repository 'https://github.com/myself/deletedrepository/' not found**. I looked everywhere in the settings and did't find any traces of my deleted repository, maybe i'm missing something? Is there any way to clone repository from github without connection to local one?

Comment: Do you mean it tries cloning from 'https://github.com/myself/deletedrepository/ regardless of what URL you enter in the Clone dialog? Does it work fine in the command line?

Comment: Yeah, exactly . i just tried this one more time in project folder using "git clone" in Git Bash with same result, so i guess this issue doesn't related to Intellij Idea.

Comment: I find the headline of this question missleading, because it sounds like a general question but seems to cover a specific case. It could better read "Cloning from git repository fails in Intellij Idea after having deleted a specific repository".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, there is an incorrect global git config. If your global gitconfig has the [remote "origin"] section, it could cause such issues. CHeck the `git config --global --list` oitput and make sure there are no `remote.origin.url` and `remote.origin.fetch` entires there

See e.g. [git clone always clone the same repo no matter what url I provide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005718/git-clone-always-clone-the-same-repo-no-matter-what-url-i-provide)

Answer (score 0):

You can clone a repository to a different local directory, simply create a different dir.

I had similar issues, I got around it by using VSC-> Checkout From Version Control -> Git. 
Or could try a *git clone* from your command prompt or DOS, depending on what you're using, and opening that directory from your IntelliJ